# problem with my login servlet page

Tags: servlets

I'm facing problem with my website where I try to let the user insert the username and password to login to home page, but it show me this error

> HTTP Status 404-The requested resource () is not available

It's seems that the html page does not get any result from the servlet. I'm not sure but can anybody help me and tell me what I am missing?

Here is my servlet:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class enter extends HttpServlet {

  private Connection myCon;
  private PreparedStatement myStmt;

    @Override
  public void init() {

System.out.println("init");
    try {

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

       try {
        System.out.println("connecting");
      myCon = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/auk","root","password");

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
    }
  } 

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    ResultSet result;
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String query, colName, dat, user;
    int numCols, index;
    ResultSetMetaData resultMd;

     query = "Select Pass from user where Username=?";

    try {
      myStmt = myCon.prepareStatement(query);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
         user=request.getParameter("user");
     myStmt.setString(1, user);   

     result=myStmt.executeQuery();
     String userpass=result.getString(1);

     out.println ("userpass selected from the table is = "+userpass);

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>JDBCServlet</title></head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.print("<p><b>The query is: </b>" + query + "</p>");

    try {

      result = myStmt.executeQuery(query);

      resultMd = result.getMetaData();
      numCols = resultMd.getColumnCount();

      out.println("<table border>");
      out.println("<caption> <b> Query Results </b> </caption>");
      out.println("<tr>");

     out.print("<th> Welcome " + user + " </th>");
      for (index = 1; index <= numCols; index++) {
        colName = resultMd.getColumnLabel(index);
        out.print("<th>" + colName + "</th>");
      }
        out.println("</tr>");

        while (result.next()) {
        out.println("<tr>");

        for (index = 0; index < numCols; index++) {
        dat = result.getString(index + 1);
        out.println("<td>" + dat + "</td>");
      } 

      out.println("</tr>");
    } 
    out.println("</table>");
  } 
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    out.println("</body></html>");

    }     

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(enter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(enter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

That error just means that there's nothing which is listening on the URL.

So, either the URL is plain wrong (case sensitive!), or the Servlet isn't listening on that URL at all, or the Servlet failed to startup. Hard to tell based on the as far given information. You need to verify the URL in browser address bar, the servlet mapping in `web.xml` and the server startup logs.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, assigning expensive DB resources like `Connection` and on as instance variable of a servlet is an *extremely bad idea*. You should open and close those resources in the shortest possible scope inside the same method.

Comment: Thank you for your request and explain but i didn't get your solution. can you show me in my code where is the mistake.

Comment: The mistake is not in the code shown as far. That code is **not even reached** at all. As mentioned in the answer: *You need to verify the URL in browser address bar, the servlet mapping in web.xml and the server startup logs.* Include this information in your question if you stucks.